# Use SQL views instead of tables with Asterisk dynamic realtime

Tags: postgresql, asterisk, voip

I had hoped that I would be able to use an SQL view instead of a table to provide e.g. `iaxusers` and `iaxpeers` to Asterisk via dynamic realtime (ARA).

I have just noticed that `iaxpeers` apparently requires several columns for Asterisk to store peer-specific information: `ipaddr`, `port`, `regseconds`. Therefore a simple view won't do.

Is there a way to still get by with a view e.g. for `iaxpeers` or do I have to create a table and perhaps sync it with my core data structures (also tables) with triggers instead of a view's (more convenient) `SELECT` statement -- push instead of pull, so to speak. (I am using PostgreSQL, whose views are apparently read-only.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have concluded that views (instead of tables) are appropriate for some, but not all dynamic ARA families, and that they are not appropriate for `iaxpeers` at least in the case of PostgreSQL. This is because Asterisk requires read-write access e.g. for this family.

I have hence switched over from a view to a table. Its rows are now "pushed" from my core data structures (i.e. other tables) by triggers, rather than "pulled" by the view.