# Connect Asterisk system to SIP provider with Asterisk dynamic realtime

Tags: asterisk, voip, sip

Is it possible to connect an Asterisk system to a SIP provider with Asterisk dynamic realtime ([ARA](https://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+RealTime))?

In other words, is it possible to configure a table (or perhaps [view](https://serverfault.com/questions/796433/use-sql-views-instead-of-tables-with-asterisk-dynamic-realtime)) such as `sippeers` for family `sippeers` in `/etc/asterisk/extconfig.conf`

```
[settings]
sippeers => odbc,mydb,sippeers
```

and insert a row into that table with information about connection establishment that would normally (without ARA) reside in `/etc/asterisk/sip.conf`

```
[general]
register => user:md5secret@sip.my-sip-provider.com
```

If so, how would that information look in terms of specific column values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments in the default version of `/etc/asterisk/sip.conf` pointed to a solution. An entry of the form

```
register => user:md5secret@sip.my-sip-provider.com
```

is apparently equivalent to a `[device]` section with the following parameters

```
type = peer
host = sip.my-sip-provider.com
defaultuser = user
md5secret = md5secret
callbackextension = s
```

The default value `'s'` for `callbackextension` applies because the first form does not specify another extension.

A mapping between such an entry and a row in a table such as `sippeers` is covered by the normal rules for [Asterisk RealTime SIP](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+RealTime+Sip).